# Handling server authentication Regex SSH Read

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, phpseclib

I am trying to handle the message to automatically connect when a new ip/server is being logged into, this is what I have so far:

```
    $read = $this->ssh->read('(Password:)|(Are you sure you want to continue connecting)', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
            if (preg_match('/Are you sure you want to continue connecting/',$read)) {
                $this->ssh->write('yes');
                $this->ssh->write("\n");
                $this->ssh->read('Permanently added');

                $this->ssh->write('ssh '.$this->userid.'@'.$this->testIPAddress);
                $this->ssh->write("\n");                
                $read = $this->ssh->read('(Password:)|(Are you sure you want to continue connecting)', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
            } else if ($this->ssh->isTimeout()) { 
                $testLineHideResult = "Connection failed";
            }

            if ($testLineHideResult == '') {
                $this->ssh->write($this->passwd);
                $this->ssh->write("\n");
                $this->ssh->setTimeout(25);
```

But I get the following error message:

```
preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier '|'
```

Can you help me fix this or rewrite it to get it to work? Any suggestions are helpful :)

Comment: It seems like the "|" in the $read variable is issuing this problem. Does it actually help the function you're using?

Comment: Yeah that is causing the problem, I need it to read either "password" or "are you sure you want to continue connecting".

Comment: Use `$this->ssh->read('/Password:|Are you sure you want to continue connecting/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);`

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is the the regex inside SSH `read()` is the same regex as should be used in the `preg_` PHP functions, and thus requires regex delimiters. You may check the syntax at the [*phpseclib documentation*](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_sudo) Web page.

Use, say,

```
$this->ssh->read('/Password:|Are you sure you want to continue connecting/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
                  ^                                                      ^
```